# Simple Correlation in R

Tags: r

I made my first script in R with Rstudio. Is a sible correlation.
The result of the code is the image below. I don't know how to move the trend line inside of the "point cloud" and how to change the color of trend line.

[image]

```
summary(Landsat_7$Pixel_Value)
summary(Landsat_8$Pixel_Value)
Landsat7<-(Landsat_7)
Landsat8<-(Landsat_8)
head(cbind(Landsat7, Landsat8))
Landsat7 = Landsat_7$Pixel_Value    # Landsat 7
Landsat8 = Landsat_8$Pixel_Value    # Landsat 8
plot(Landsat7, Landsat8, 
     xlab= "Landsat 7",             # x−axis label  
     ylab= "Landsat 8")             # y−axis label
abline(lm(Landsat7 ~ Landsat8))     # trend line
```

Comment: Will you provide your data here? I am guessing you are not using the correct syntax or commands

Comment: You just need to switch the `7` and `8` in your `lm()`: `abline(lm(Landsat8 ~ Landsat7),col="red")`

Comment: Respect... to you my friend. thank you very much It was so simple.

Comment: The order of parameters in plot is `plot(x_variable, y_variable)` but for lm it is `lm(y_variable ~ x_variable)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you plotted your original line but this will help you plot the least squares line:

```
x=runif(100,1,5)
y=2*x+rnorm(100)

plot(x,y)
fit=lm(y~x)
abline(fit,col=2)
```

Comment: or if you want to do the same using the obtained regression parameters explicitly: 'abline(fit$coefficients[1], fit$coefficients[2])'

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the same formula in the plot() function as in the lm() function:

```
plot(Landsat7 ~ Landsat8)
abline(lm(Landsat7 ~ Landsat8))
```